# Close Dropdown When Clicking Adjacent

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slidedown, slideup

I am using the following for a dropdown menu. It works great, however, I can't figure out how to get an open dropdown to slideUp if somewhere in the body is clicked, or another dropdown is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('.nav li').click(function() {

  var slideToggle = this;
  if ($('ul', this).is(':visible')) {
      $('ul', this).slideUp(function() {
          $(slideToggle).removeClass('active');
      });
  }
  else {
      $('ul', this).slideDown();
      $(slideToggle).addClass('active');
  }
});
});
```

View it action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ngh5C/1/

What would be the easiest way to go about what i've asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of event bubbling and bind a click handler to a suitable parent container (e.g. body). Check the target in the handler and if it isn't one of your menus, use a selector to find the open menu and close it.

Here's a simple example as a starting point:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ngh5C/6/

Try this fiddle to keep only one open at a time:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ngh5C/7/

If you really only want to close the neighbors of the item clicked (which is an odd requirement), then this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ngh5C/8/

Comment: I came up with almost the exact same thing right before you posted the jsfiddle. In a different way, but yours is less lines and more efficient. One problem now, adding .removeClass('active') after your .slideUp() does not remove the active class as it should.

Comment: Never mind, I was removing the active class from the child ul, instead of the parent li in which the active was originally assigned to.

Can you help me in getting this to close an open menu if clicking on the adjacent menu?

Comment: @AjTroxell: I've changed the fiddle to keep only one menu open at a time. I assume that's what you wanted. If you really want to only restrict adjacent menus, that just requires a slight tweak to the selector.